# Download Notepad++ with PowerShell

Tags: powershell, download

I want to download 7zip files with PowerShell for example Notepad++
I tried

`"Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plsu/releases/download/v8.1.4/npp8.1.4.portable.7zip -OutFile package.zip"`

and I get the following Error Message

```
Invoke-WebRequest : Die Anfrage wurde abgebrochen: Die Verbindung wurde unerwartet getrennt..
In Zeile:1 Zeichen:1
+ Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-p ...
+ ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidOperation: (System.Net.HttpWebRequest:HttpWebRequest) [Invoke-WebRequest], WebExc
   eption
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : WebCmdletWebResponseException,Microsoft.PowerShell.Commands.InvokeWebRequestCommand
```

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Can you translate the german error message into english one ?

Comment: "Request aborted: Connection was unexepected canceled
in Line:1 charakter:1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not doing something wrong. It's the good command, it works with another link.

You link `https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plsu/releases/download/v8.1.4/npp8.1.4.portable.7zip` return 404 error, so you can't download it.

If you want to be sure, you can try with this link: `https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.1.4/npp.8.1.4.portable.7z`

And so, run this command:

```
Invoke-WebRequest https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/download/v8.1.4/npp.8.1.4.portable.7z -OutFile package.zip
```

Which works fine.

(Warn: I take first file that I found, so maybe it's not the extension that you want)

All available files are [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases/tag/v8.1.4) and all release are [here](https://github.com/notepad-plus-plus/notepad-plus-plus/releases).